# Include libraries in GHDL

Tags: vhdl, simulation, floating-point

I'm using GHDL to simulate some designs that I'm doing. Now, I included the `float_pkg` package to work with floats in Sigasi but when I'm simulating in GHDL it states that `primary unit "float_pkg" not found in library "ieee"`

How can I add this new library to GHDL? Copy/paste to the GHDL>lib where we have two folders "v93" and "v87" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You'll need to compile it, unless a compiled version was part of your install.

Comment: I didn't compile the library, I didn't  thought it was necessary. How can I do that?
Also, the GHDL compiler is complaining about "math_real"

Comment: All I see in [this](http://www.vhdl.org/fphdl/vhdl.html) package in a compile.msi file without any instructions.

Comment: They are compiled as part of the install in ghdl-0.33, and available in VHDL-2008 mode. That wasn't the case in ghdl-0.25, so the best way forward is probably to upgrade. https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/files/Builds/ghdl-0.33/

Comment: Yes! That solved it. Thank you very much and post this as an answer please, for me to mark as correct. Thank you!